# How can i run the App package created with NSIS without admin rights

Tags: package, installation, system, nsis, packaging

I've created one app package using NSIS which requires admin rights to run. I want the package to be installed without admin rights. I've tried below options to make it work but none of them worked.

1. Added `!define MUTIUSER_EXECUTIONLEVEL user` in **nsisconf.nsh**
   file
   Added `RequestExecutionLevel user` in
   **nsisconf.nsh** file
2. Added `!define MUTIUSER_EXECUTIONLEVEL user` in **UserVars.nsi**
   file under ProgramFiles\NSIS\Examples
   Added `RequestExecutionLevel user` in
   **UserVars.nsi** file under ProgramFiles\NSIS\Examples

What else I can do to allow the package to run without admin rights?Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as i know, if there is an installation involved, then you obviously need an authorisation from the admin or an user who got the admin rights in order to install the soft.

Answer (score 2):

Add `!define MULTIUSER_EXECUTIONLEVEL user` at the **top** of **your** .NSI file and `RequestExecutionLevel user` at the **bottom**. (You only need one of them but without example code I can't tell which one you need.)

`nsisconf.nsh` is not the right place for this because it applies to all installers and including this file is optional.

Comment: Hi Anders, I've tried adding !define MULTIUSER_EXECUTIONLEVEL user at the top and RequestExecutionLevel user at the bottom of  UsersVars.NSI file. I've even tried adding only one of them but still it is asking for admin rights while launching the app package created.

Comment: Why UsersVars? You need to put it in the .NSI file you are compiling.

Comment: Thanks Anders, I got your point after reading this post at this link-https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/using-nsis-build-application-installers. Earlier I was trying to create package using NSIS wizard only and i was not getting .NSI file for my package. Does it get generated if I create package using NSIS wizard only? If yes, Where can I find it. Please help me understand this thing.

Comment: You can technically pipe input to the compiler but that is very rare, I'm sure it has generated a .NSI file for you, you just have to figure out where it has been saved.